# How to obtain the fisheye model from blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, camera

I am using a fish eye camera to do some animations. Next, I want to validate a 3D reconstruction algorithm. So, I need the projection matrix of the fish eye camera. I know that it not possible to approximate fisheye by as a perspective projection. I need some tutorial and what I understand is the coordinate (u,v) of a 3D point X (x,y,z) in space is linked with the radius r which is the distance between the center of the image (circle) and the coordinates (u,v), and the angle ***theta*** defined by the incident ray define by the point X and the center optical (or the center of the sphere). Any comment? Any help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about fisheye lens reconstruction algorithms, and not specifically related to blender.